# Ошибка генерации в OpenApi ERROR o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver

Tags: swagger, openapi

Столкнулся с ошибкой генерации модели

```
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver - Illegal schema found with $ref combined with other properties, no properties should be defined alongside a $ref:
 class ObjectSchema {
    class Schema {
        type: object
        format: null
        $ref: #/components/schemas/image
        description: null
        title: null
        multipleOf: null
        maximum: null
        exclusiveMaximum: null
        minimum: null
        exclusiveMinimum: null
        maxLength: null
        minLength: null
        pattern: null
        maxItems: null
        minItems: null
        uniqueItems: null
        maxProperties: null
        minProperties: null
        required: null
        not: null
        properties: null
        additionalProperties: null
        nullable: null
        readOnly: null
        writeOnly: null
        example: null
        externalDocs: null
        deprecated: null
        discriminator: null
        xml: null
    }
}
```

Гуглил, но не нашел решения проблемы. Может кто-то знает как решить или обходной путь?
Генерирую такую модель:

```
post:
  parameters:
    - in: query
      name: type
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        enum:
          - profile
      description: Type
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            allOf:
              - $ref: "../schemas/common/defaultResponse.yaml"
              - type: object
                properties:
                  content:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      popup:
                        type: object
                        properties:
                          title:
                            type: string
                            enum:
                              - Code for use
                          description:
                            type: string
                          comment:
                            type: string
                          code:
                            type: string
                          qr:
                            type: string
                          button_label:
                            type: string
                            enum:
                              - Close sheet
                      reload_interval:
                        type: integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что enum содержал строку из нескольких слов, то есть уже содержал данные в модели, а такого не должно быть.
Исправил удалением enum, так как в нем содержались данные, а не модель данных:

было

```
...
title:
   type: string
   enum:
      - Code for use
```

стало:

```
title:
   type: string
```